# elements specifically for :hover overriding the an equivalent class for :active

Tags: html, css, hover, states

I have code to have a background with a font color assigned with one class then have separate classes for changing the color on :hover or :active but the :active state does not trigger unless I remove the :hover specific class. [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bjackson2016/pen/JKLVQk)

HTML:

```
<div class="backgroundRed backgroundGreenHover backgroundBlueActive" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.backgroundRed, .backgroundRedHover:hover, .backgroundRedActive:active{background:red;}
    .backgroundGreen, .backgroundGreenHover:hover, .backgroundGreenActive:active{background:green;}
    .backgroundBlue, .backgroundBlueHover:hover, .backgroundBlueActive:active{background:blue;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:active` pseudo-class should go after `:hover`, otherwise the `:hover` overwrites (The order for the link-relates pseudo-clasess is: `:link | :visited | :hover | :active`.). You code example works as expected but if you change the classes the `:active` pseudo-class never applies.

```css
.backgroundRed,
.backgroundRedHover:hover,
.backgroundRedActive:active {
  background: red;
}

.backgroundGreen,
.backgroundGreenHover:hover,
.backgroundGreenActive:active {
  background: green;
}

.backgroundBlue,
.backgroundBlueHover:hover,
.backgroundBlueActive:active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundRed backgroundBlueHover backgroundGreenActive" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

You need more CSS lines but reordering the classes with `:active` after the `:hover` works fine.

```css
.backgroundRed,
.backgroundRedHover:hover {
  background: red;
}

.backgroundGreen,
.backgroundGreenHover:hover {
  background: green;
}

.backgroundBlue,
.backgroundBlueHover:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.backgroundRedActive:active {
  background: red;
}

.backgroundGreenActive:active {
  background: green;
}

.backgroundBlueActive:active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundRed backgroundBlueHover backgroundGreenActive" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```